# TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function in date format using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I am doing the date format to the input text using jQuery, it shows this type of error.

Here is my code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="date" name="bday"/>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert();
        $("#date").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
    });
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have to include the jQuery plugin after jQuery.

Comment: sorry I dont understand...!!!

Comment: Swap the two script elements.

Comment: `jquery.mask.js` this file must be referenced after `jquery.min.js` .. so swap yout first and second lines..

Comment: I have already done that but then also the same error is coming.

Answer (score 2):

Swapping the scripts by putting in jquery first and then the mask works, as has been posted in the comments. Check the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert();
        $("#date").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="date" name="bday"/>
```

Comment: sorry boss same issues is coming.

Comment: Did you run code snippet? It works fine there. It's the exact same code of yours with the scripts interchanged.

Comment: @JosanIracheta Thank you.